# How to use WMSProvider class for custom map providers

Tags: gmap.net

i'm new to GMap.NET and i've been trying to find out how i can make use of a custom map provider.

I'm not too sure where and how to start, so i have not really tried anything but I've noticed that there is a WMSProvider class and there has been a post by someone saying that the WMSProvider class can be used for this so i'm hoping someone can give me advice on how this class can be used. Thanks!